# Pandas: use groupby to count difference between dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, timedelta

I have df:

```
i,Unnamed,ID,url,used_at,active_seconds,domain,subdomain,search_engine,search_term,diff_time,period
0,322015,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/antoninaribina,2015-12-31 09:16:05,35,vk.com,vk.com,None,None,,1
1,838267,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed,2015-12-31 09:16:38,54,vk.com,vk.com,None,None,33.0,1
2,838271,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed?section=photos,2015-12-31 09:17:32,34,vk.com,vk.com,None,None,54.0,1
3,322026,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed?section=photos&z=photo143297356_397216312%2Ffeed1_143297356_1451504298,2015-12-31 09:18:06,4,vk.com,vk.com,None,None,34.0,1
4,838275,0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca,vk.com/feed?section=photos,2015-12-31 09:18:10,4,vk.com,vk.com,None,None,4.0,1
5,322028,7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464,vk.com/feed?section=comments,2015-12-29 09:18:14,8,vk.com,vk.com,None,None,4.0,1
6,322029,7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464,megarand.ru/contest/121070,2015-12-30 09:18:22,16,megarand.ru,megarand.ru,None,None,8.0,1
7,1870917,7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464,vk.com/feed?section=comments,2015-12-31 09:18:38,6,vk.com,vk.com,None,None,16.0,1
```

I need to print dirrerence between first and last date to every `ID`. How can I do it?
I tried to use `df.groupby('ID')['used_at'].diff().dt.seconds` but it print difference between every 2 strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need  `groupby` with difference with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
g = df.groupby('ID')['used_at']
print (g.first() - g.last())
ID
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca   -1 days +23:57:55
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464   -3 days +23:59:36
Name: used_at, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Or apply [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.groupby('ID')['used_at'].apply(lambda g: g.iloc[0] - g.iloc[-1]))
ID
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca   -1 days +23:57:55
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464   -3 days +23:59:36
Name: used_at, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

With converting `timedelta` to [`seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html):

```
g = df.groupby('ID')['used_at']
print ((g.first() - g.last()).dt.seconds)
ID
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    86275
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464    86376
Name: used_at, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby('ID')['used_at'].apply(lambda g: g.iloc[0] - g.iloc[-1]).dt.seconds)
ID
0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca    86275
7602962fb83ac2e2a0cb44158ca88464    86376
Name: used_at, dtype: int64
```

Thank you  `juanpa.arrivillaga` for [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915186/pandas-use-groupby-to-count-difference-between-dates/38915411?noredirect=1#comment65188500_38915411):

If datetimes are sorted, you can use:

```
df.groupby('ID').used_at.min() - df.groupby('ID').used_at.max()
```

**Timings**:

```
In [216]: %timeit (a(df))
The slowest run took 4.30 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.78 ms per loop

In [217]: %timeit (b(df))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 ms per loop

In [218]: %timeit (df.groupby('ID')['used_at'].apply(lambda g: g.iloc[0] - g.iloc[-1]).dt.seconds)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop

In [219]: %timeit (df.groupby('ID').agg(['first','last']).apply( lambda r: r['used_at','first'] - r['used_at','last'], axis=1).dt.seconds)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.4 ms per loop
```

Code for timings:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

def a(df):
    g = df.groupby('ID')['used_at']
    return ((g.first() - g.last()).dt.seconds)

def b(df):
    g = df.groupby('ID')['used_at']
    return ((g.min() - g.max()).dt.seconds)
```

Comment: perhaps `df.groupby('ID').used_at.min()` and  `f.groupby('ID').used_at.max()` would be better in case it is out of order.

Comment: If I try to do a new df, where should I write that? `rep['time_to_buy'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'buy']).agg({'active_seconds': sum}).rename(columns={'active_seconds': 'count_sec'}).reset_index().merge(df2, how='left', on=['ID','buy']).apply(lambda x: x['date'] if x['buy']==1 else x['count_sec'],axis=1)`

Comment: Hard question, because I have no column `buy`, so i cannot test it. But it seems your command return some new `DataFrame`, not Series, so you can use `df1 = df.groupby(['ID', ...`. But if need append output with difference, you need merge I guess. The best is add to code `df2`, DataFrame with `buy` and then it can be more clear.

Comment: hm, okey, I try add that to existing table with `rep['time_to_buy'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'buy']).agg({'active_seconds': sum}).rename(columns={'active_seconds': 'count_sec'}).reset_index().merge(df2, how='left', on=['ID','buy']).apply(lambda x: x['date'] if x['buy']==1 else x['count_sec'],axis=1)
` but it returns `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

Comment: If remove `.apply(lambda x: x['date'] if x['buy']==1 else x['count_sec'],axis=1)` still error?

Comment: I add uncorrect. I try  this `rep['days_to_buy'] = df.groupby('ID').agg(['first','last']).apply( lambda r: r['used_at','last'] - r['used_at','first'], axis=1).reset_index()
`

Comment: Hmmm, I see problem. You cannot add this way new data. You need firt create new DataFrame like `rep1= df.groupby('ID').agg(['first','last']).apply( lambda r: r['used_at','last'] - r['used_at','first'], axis=1).reset_index()` and then it merge or concat to another dataframe like `pd.merge(df, rep1, on=['come_columns'])`.

Comment: How can I give a name to this column? it print under the column `0`

Comment: Try add `.reset_index(name='new_name')` and if it doesnt work, need `.rename(columns={0:'new_name'})`

Comment: Can you say, why if I use `dt.seconds` after string I use `0    0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca  37653
1    031ce36695306ac09ae905927a753f33  30762` But I don't use this I get                                   ёID                0
0    0120bc30e78ba5582617a9f3d6dfd8ca 25 days 10:27:33
1    031ce36695306ac09ae905927a753f33 25 days 08:32:42` and this values are not equal

Comment: I think it return bad data, because it cut off days. Try `print (g.last() - g.first())`, then `print ((g.last() - g.first()).dt.seconds)` and `print (df.groupby('ID')['used_at'].apply(lambda g: g.iloc[-1] - g.iloc[0]).dt.seconds.reset_index())`, where are swap last with first.

Answer (score 1):

there is a oneline.

```
df.groupby('ID').agg(['first','last']).apply( lambda r: r['used_at','last'] - r['used_at','first'], axis=1)
```

first group by column `ID`, then for each group take first and last element and calculate the difference `last - first`.

Comment: how can I add it to existing table? I try `rep['days_to_buy'] = df.groupby('ID').agg(['first','last']).apply( lambda r: r['used_at','last'] - r['used_at','first'], axis=1).reset_index()

` but it returns `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`