# Pandas Dataframe: difference between all dates for each unique id

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, group-by

```
[In 621]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[44,44,44,88,88,90,95],
                   'Status': ['Reject','Submit','Draft','Accept','Submit',
                   'Submit','Draft'],
                              'Datetime': ['2018-11-24 08:56:02',
                              '2018-10-24 18:12:02','2018-10-24 08:12:02', 
                              '2018-10-29 13:17:02','2018-10-24 10:12:02',
                              '2018-12-30 08:43:12', '2019-01-24 06:12:02']
                              }, columns = ['id','Status', 'Datetime'])
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])                              
df

Out[621]: 
   id  Status            Datetime
0  44  Reject 2018-11-24 08:56:02
1  44  Submit 2018-10-24 18:12:02
2  44   Draft 2018-10-24 08:12:02
3  88  Accept 2018-10-29 13:17:02
4  88  Submit 2018-10-24 10:12:02
5  90  Submit 2018-12-30 08:43:12
6  95   Draft 2019-01-24 06:12:02
```

What I am trying to get is another column, e.g. `df['Time in Status']` which is the time that `id` spent at that status.

I've looked at `df.groupby()` but only found answers ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915186/pandas-use-groupby-to-count-difference-between-dates/38915746)) for working out between two dates (e.g. first and last) regardless how how many dates are in between.

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])                              
g = df.groupby('id')['Datetime']
print(df.groupby('id')['Datetime'].apply(lambda g: g.iloc[-1] - g.iloc[0])) 

id
44   -32 days +23:16:00
88    -6 days +20:55:00
90      0 days 00:00:00
95      0 days 00:00:00
Name: Datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The closest I've come to getting the result is [DataFrameGroupBy.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html)

```
df['Time in Status'] = df.groupby('id')['Datetime'].diff()
df
   id  Status            Datetime          Time in Status
0  44  Reject 2018-11-24 08:56:02                NaT
1  44  Submit 2018-10-24 18:12:02 -31 days +09:16:00
2  44   Draft 2018-10-24 08:12:02  -1 days +14:00:00
3  88  Accept 2018-10-29 13:17:02                NaT
4  88  Submit 2018-10-24 10:12:02  -6 days +20:55:00
5  90  Submit 2018-12-30 08:43:12                NaT
6  95   Draft 2019-01-24 06:12:02                NaT
```

However there are two issues with this. First, how can I do this calculation starting with the earliest date and working through until the end? E.g. so in row `2`, instead of `-1 days +14:00:00` it would be `0 Days 10:00:00`? Or is this easier to solve by rearranging the order of the data before hand?

The other issue is the NaT. If there is no date to compare with, then the current day (i.e. datetime.now) would be used. I could apply this afterwards easy enough, but I was wondering if there might be a better solution to finding and replacing all the NaT values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly you are right, first is necessary sorting [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with both columns:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'Datetime'])
df['Time in Status'] = df.groupby('id')['Datetime'].diff()
print (df)
   id  Status            Datetime   Time in Status
2  44   Draft 2018-10-24 08:12:02              NaT
1  44  Submit 2018-10-24 18:12:02  0 days 10:00:00
0  44  Reject 2018-11-24 08:56:02 30 days 14:44:00
4  88  Submit 2018-10-24 10:12:02              NaT
3  88  Accept 2018-10-29 13:17:02  5 days 03:05:00
5  90  Submit 2018-12-30 08:43:12              NaT
6  95   Draft 2019-01-24 06:12:02              NaT
```

Comment: so this worked with some amendments. I had to use `diff(-1)` to get to calculate using the row below, so for 44 the time on Draft is `['Datetime'][0] - ['Datetime'][1]` etc. Then multiply by -1 to get time spent in that status.
`df['Time in Status'] = df.groupby('id')['Datetime'].diff(-1)*(-1)`